# JavaScript / Jquery to elide part of '<figcaption>'element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have [this site](http://www.familyhistoryconferencenwa.org) on [Squarespace](http://www.squarespace.com). On a [/test](http://www.familyhistoryconferencenwa.org/test) page I have a block quote. In Squarespace, the block quote is followed by the author's name preceded by an em dash. This is in a <figcaption> element.

I want to elide that em dash. It will have to be done with some JavaScript or JQuery. Can anyone provide the code?

Mille grazie!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you would omit that specific character for each instance of the figcaption tag.

```
$('figcaption').each(function(){ 
  $(this).text($(this).text().replace('—','')) 
})
```

Comment: So sorry not to have gotten back to this question earlier. Thanks for the script; it works perfectly.